# echo $? from python

Tags: python, linux

hello I am trying to get a result back (which I KNOW is 1) from an external python script being called from my other script. when echo $? from command line I get 1 but when I try to call echo $? from the python to get the result from the python script I get 0 in the script. here is my code:

```
 os.system(pythonPath+"serialWait.py "+dev+" "+brate+" login") //this
 os.system(pythonPath+"serialCommand.py "+dev+" "+brate+" reset") //this works      
 value = subprocess.call('echo $?', shell=True)
>//here is where my issue lies I am trying to call the exit code from the previous python script but only get the true value from terminal
```

Comment: Why are you using Python to make the shell run another Python script? Can you not import the other modules and just run them from one script?

Comment: You have 3 separate shells there. Don't use `os.system()` for anything ever, and do get the return values from scripts using the mechanisms already available in the subprocess module...

Comment: @cricket_007 I am new to python, but I believe what I am doing is acceptable because the python script is a very specific 1 time run used in and out of other scripts (i.e. alot of automated tasks in bash) if you have any suggests though I am always willing to learn

Comment: @Wooble so i should use sub process?

Comment: BTW, using extensions (`.py` or otherwise) on executable commands -- no matter whether they're written in a scripting language or not -- is bad form. You don't run `ls.elf`, after all. If you use setuptools, then setup.py install will create executable wrappers (with no extension on them!) for you automatically.

Comment: @user1779617, yes, you should. `os.system()` creates security bugs: If your `dev` contains `$(rm -rf .)`, for instance, a shell will run that command; whereas `subprocess` without `shell=True` is safe. [That's not an limited to Python; the C library `system()` call and all its parallels in other languages have the same issues].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well its good to learn these things thank you, though I only called them .py so i could remember what they were lol (even though I put them in a python folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible: `$?` is a variable that exists only for the duration of *a single shell*. Every time you call `os.system()`, that creates a new shell: The old one has already exited, so variables internal to that shell such as `$?` no longer exist.

Use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['serialWait.py', dev, brate, 'login'])
p1.wait()
if p1.returncode != 0:
  print 'Process failed'
```

If all you want to do is throw an exception for any nonzero result, use `subprocess.check_call()` for that purpose.

Comment: cool many thanks, just trying it out now. im not doing bad for day 2 on python...